# Oracle APEX Automation Schedule

Tags: oracle, automation, oracle-apex, schedule

Is it possible to exceute oracle apex automation on a specific day of the month(example every 28th of the month),,,once a month,,monthly? so far the settings only offer - weekly, daily,etc,

Is it possible to tweak through the Schedule Expression? (Example: `FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;BYHOUR=23;BYMINUTE=0`)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `INTERVAL=28` should execute it at 28th every month. Is this what you search for?

Comment: im not sure if interval would work,,months are not even,,im working on a apartment invoice system which gathers data on utilities every 27th of the month so it is ideal to execute at exactly the 28th,,

Comment: i think the interval is the number of execution times on chosen e.g. daily,weekly,hour,minute,  so chosing 28 on day means executing 28times in a day thats how i understand it-im not sure

Comment: No, it will mean execute with step 28 days

Comment: FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=28;BYHOUR=23;BYMINUTE=0 ///would this execute every 28th day of the month or every 28days since execution?

Comment: right now i have to set interval = 29 to make it execute on November 28th

Comment: IMHO no, set to 28 to get in on 28th

Comment: i already tried setting interval = 28 but the next execution schedule is set on November 27,,then its short 1 day

Comment: setting interval = 28 ---- NEXT RUN 11/27/2021 01:00:00 PM

Comment: hm, this will mean it count from current day :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want it to fire every month, so `FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1`. Then it should be on the 28th day of the month, so `BYMONTHDAY=28`. Hours and minutes don't really matter so just put `BYHOUR=8;BYMINUTE=0` or whatever you prefer.

There is a very simple way to test this. APEX automation use the oracle scheduling calendar syntax, which can be evaluated using `dbms_scheduler.evaluate_calendar_string`

```
DECLARE
 start_date        TIMESTAMP;
 return_date_after TIMESTAMP;
 next_run_date     TIMESTAMP;
 l_interval        VARCHAR2(500) := 'FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTHDAY=28;BYHOUR=8;BYMINUTE=0';
BEGIN
  start_date := current_timestamp;
  return_date_after := start_date;
  FOR i IN 1..5
  LOOP
    dbms_scheduler.evaluate_calendar_string
    (
      l_interval, 
      start_date,
      return_date_after, 
      next_run_date
    );
    
    dbms_output.put_line('next_run_date: ' || TO_CHAR(next_run_date,'fmDay, DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI SS'));
    return_date_after := next_run_date;
  END LOOP;
END;
/



next_run_date: Sunday, 28-NOV-2021 8:0 59
next_run_date: Tuesday, 28-DEC-2021 8:0 59
next_run_date: Friday, 28-JAN-2022 8:0 59
next_run_date: Monday, 28-FEB-2022 8:0 59
next_run_date: Monday, 28-MAR-2022 8:0 59
```

Comment: thank you very very much, this solves it,,a thousand thanks to you koen!